# Cocos2d sprite flicker while moving

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am using cocos2d-2 to move sprites from left to right. Here is the code I am using in the update method to move the sprites,

```
-(void) update:(ccTime)delta
{
    for (CCSprite* sprite in self.spriteBatch.children)
    {
        CGPoint pos = sprite.position;
        pos.x -= (self.scrollSpeed * factor.floatValue) * (delta * 50);
        sprite.position = pos;
        }
}
```

The sprites are moving without any problems, but they are flickering while in motion. I am testing this on a iPhone 4 with iOS version 5.1.1. I read through the forums and tried setting setDepthTest:NO and setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection2D, but still they are flickering while moving. Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: just a curiosity : why not move self.spriteBatch (assuming it is a CCSpriteBatchNode or descends from CCNode), instead of its children one by one?

Comment: That is because, each of the children are moved at different speed, however I have not pasted that part of the code here.

Comment: do you really mean flicker (visible/not visible)? Or unsteady motion? Which cocos2d version? Do you use vertexZ?

Comment: I mean, the sprites shake when they move. They are visible all the time and kind of like a shaky motion. I am using cocos2d version v2.0.0. I am not sure what is meant by vertexz. I have used the z property in cocos2d, and added the children to the sprite batch.

Comment: I have the same issue, setDepthTest:NO and setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection2D do not help. Have you had solution?

Answer (score -1):

I believe you should read http://www.cocos2d-x.org/news/24. I've used this code and resolved my problem.

```
CCDirector::sharedDirector()->setDepthTest(false);
```

Comment: The poster said he tried setDepthTest:NO and setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection2D.